Pricing / valuing anticipated repayment date
I am a long time lurker, and frankly not a quant, but have deep respect for those that are.
I have found myself in a situation dealing with some features on debt that I am trying to figure out how best to value / price.
The one that after some research, I haven’t been able to find an answer to (prompting me to register here and ask), is around Anticipated Repayment Dates.
Basically an asset backed security has a legal final maturity of 30 years, but an “anticipated repayment date” of say 5 years. If it breaches this however it must pay additional interest which ends up being struck at something like 10 year treasury + 8%. It also kicks in 100% cash sweep of the structure.
Conceptually I’m trying to use Merton’s structural model to just get a feel for what’s going on, but I can’t quite decide what option this represents (I guess it’s like the issuer sells an expensive call to the debt holders?)
Anyhow would love to tap the collective knowledge here.
Pardon any type of if ignorance I’ve shown.

Welcome
As I see it, the borrower has written to the lender an option to borrow more money at high interest after the "anticipated date", which can be viewed equally well as a call or as a put.
As a put: loan 1 denotes the money lent for 5 years, paying some reasonable coupon. Loan 2 starts after 5 years, paying treasury + some pretty high credit spread, and some other punitive terms. The lender has given some money to the borrower, the borrower has loan 1 on his balance sheet as a liability, the lender has loan 1 on his balance sheet as an asset. After 5 years, only if the borrower's credit is so bad that they cannot borrow money at better terms than loan 2, then the borrower exercises the put on loan 2 - under this "contingent funding" scenario, the borrower gets loan 2 as liability and the lender gets loan 2 as an asset.
As a call: loan 1+2 denotes the portfolio of loans 1 and 2 above. From inception, all of loan 1+2 is the lender's asset and the borrower's liability. The lender has written a call on loan 1+2. Unless the borrower cannot borrow money at better terms than loan 2, the borrower will exercise the call in order to avoid the punitive terms of loan 2.
Under either approach, the borrower is long the option to borrow under the terms of loan 2, and the borrower's decision whether to exercise this option is driven by their ability to borrow money at better terms than loan 2 in 5 years. If the borrower is forced to take out loan 2, you should be worried about their ability to repay it.

Although the issue you nicely state here is that the borrower effectively has a poorly priced back-stop in case it can't find better refinancing terms later, the most common use case I have come across with these type structures is creative accounting. Loans with these terms often satisfy criteria to be classed with a certain duration in the financial statements when in practice they don't really live up to that because for properly going concerns they will always be repaid earlier.
